# DSX: How to create connection for Bluemix object store in DSX

Tags: data-science-experience

I have been trying to make an Object Storage instance on Bluemix available to my DSX project. The object storage instance does not appear under the list of existing data services when adding a data asset. I have tried to create a connection to the object storage instance as an external service. However, DSX complains in the find and add data tab: `Failed to retrieve Object Store Files` and is unable to upload any files as well.

I suspect that I am not configuring the external connection properly. Which object storage service credential keys do `access key` and `secret key` correspond to?

Comment: Is this object storage or IBM Softlayer Object Storage that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: It is IBM Softlayer Object Storage.

Comment: What language are you going to use in your notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

This won't help with UI integration, but will for notebook access.

I strongly recommend you look at https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/ibmos2spark (which works for Python, R and Scala).

For Python + SoftLayer credentials it would specifically be this code:

> slos = ibmos2spark.softlayer(sc, configuration_name, auth_url, tenant, username, password)
>   data = sc.textFile(slos.url(container_name, object_name))

(taken from https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/ibmos2spark/tree/master/python#softlayer )